# python multiplying instead of adding

Tags: python

The program I'm creating multiplies instead of adding. What is the problem?

```
    while True:
        winsound.Beep(4000, beatlength)
        winsound.Beep(3500, beatlength)
        stbr = stbr + stbr
        print stbr


        if stbr==25:
            break
```

Comment: So what's the error are you getting? and what is `stbr`?

Comment: it's a variable that equals 0, after the program beeps 25 times it breaks the loop. Instead of adding by one it doubles the value.

Comment: If stbr is 0 then this will never exit as 0+0 is still 0. You could also more simply write `stbr *= 2` if you want to double stbr, if you want to add by one then `stbr += 1` would be what you need.

Comment: So as AChampion said, this loop will never break.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use a for loop, e.g. `for stbr in range(25):` (`xrange` if python2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the number to itself, which is of course equivalent to multiplying it by two. Add one instead by changing:

```
stbr = stbr + stbr
```

to:

```
stbr += 1
```

Comment: However I don't understand what's the OP really wants. But if OP just want to run this loop 25 times, I think use `for i in xrange(25)` will be more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
import winsound
beatlength = 250
stbr = 0
while True:
        winsound.Beep(4000, beatlength)
        winsound.Beep(3500, beatlength)
        stbr = stbr + 1
        print stbr
        if stbr==25:
            break
```

Comment: Is that meant to read `stbr += 1`, with out the assignment stbr will never change.

Comment: Thanks for informing me